# react-native-i18n:processReleaseResources FAILED

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to React-Native and I am trying to use the Ignite boilerplate. I followed all the steps for building my first app but now I am stuck with and error and can't find the answer.
As the title says, the error is:

`:react-native-i18n:processReleaseResources FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-i18n:processReleaseResources'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt`

I am using version 0.50.4 of react-native and version 2.0.1 of react-native-cli, and running on Ubuntu.

Anyone knows what the problem could be?

Comment: I had same error (`Failed to execute aapt`) with different setup a while ago. It seems more like a gradle issue. Check this issue answer (although it's in React Navigation repo, it's probably still valid in your case): https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1976#issuecomment-325019683

Comment: Try gradle clean. Might solve it. `cd android && ./gradlew clean`